# Python and classes

Tags: python, oop, class

How i can call first.TQ in Second ? Without creating object First in Second.

```
class First:
    def __init__(self):
        self.str = ""
    def TQ(self):
        pass
    def main(self):
        T = Second(self.str) # Called here
class Second():
    def __init__(self):
        list =  {u"RANDINT":first.TQ} # List of funcs maybe called in first
        .....
        .....
        return data
```

Comment: You can't `TQ` in `Second` since `Second` doesn't have `TQ` method. You probably want `class Second(First):`. Also, you shouldn't return a value for `__init__`.

Comment: Want are you exactly trying to achieve? Your example doesn't show an example of Second calling First.TQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class First:
    def __init__(self):
        self.str = ""

    @classmethod
    def TQ(self):
        pass

    def main(self):
        T = Second(self.str) # Called here

class Second():
    def __init__(self):
        list =  {u"RANDINT":First.TQ} # List of funcs maybe called in first
        .....
        .....
        return data
```

Only if you don't intend to call method TQ from First's instance. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the TQ-metod static. After a fast checkup on Google (I am not too familiar with Python) I found this: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52304-static-methods-aka-class-methods-in-python/

It seems to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a method without creating a object of a class, you need to make a static method of if. Use the [staticmethod](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod) decorator for this. But keep in mind that static methods **do not** take the `self`-parameter, so you can not use self!

```
class First:
    @staticmethod
    def some_method():
        print 'First.some_method()'
class Second:
    def __init__(self):
        First.some_method()

s = Second()
```

In the example you posted, you already have an object of `First` since you are in `First.main()`. So you can pass the the First's class `self` to `Second`:

```
class First:
    def main(self):
        second = Second(self) # we pass the current object...
    def do_something(self):
        print 'First.do_something()'
class Second:
    def __init__(self, first): # and recieve it as first
       first.do_something()
```

Answer (score 1):

To clarify some of the answers already posted here, since I don't think any of them really make the point clearly:

Normally, when you define a method on a class in Python, it automatically gets passed as its first parameter the instance on which it is called. If you don't want this to happen, there are two things you can do:

1. Use the `@staticmethod` decorator, which will pass *no* extra argument to the function (that is; it will be called with exactly those arguments with which it looks like it should be called). This is not often useful, since it is commonly clearer just to define a global function and not worry about the class namespace.
2. Use the `@classmethod` decorator, which will pass the *class* on which the function is defined instead of `self` as the first argument. (This argument is conventionally called `cls`.) These are often used for functions which apply to the class in general, say `from_string` or some such.

---

I wonder *why* you want to do this; there may be a better way!